# role.setPosition() in Discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

In Discord.js v11 you could use `guild.setRolePosition({ role: '123456789012345678', position: 1 });` to set the position of a specific role. How can you specify a role (like i.e. 'Muted') with the new [role.setPosition()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setPosition) method? It seems to only accept a position number and a few options like `options.relative`. What I want is to assign a role position to the roles Admin, Friends, Muted in the [roleCreate()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-roleCreate) event. I know that the roleCreate event only runs when a role is created, but somehow the *'position'* parameter doesn't work well with [guild.roles.create](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create).

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildRoleManager.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) actually works fine with the `position` parameter, you just have to add it ass a property to the data object.

```js
guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Role Name',
    // any other options...
    position: 1
  },
});
```

If you still want to use [`role.setPosition()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setPosition), you'll have to fetch the role object before-hand, then call the method on that object.

```js
// <guild> is a placeholder for the guild object

// get the role by id
const role = <guild>.roles.cache.get('Role ID');

// get role by name (or other property)
const role = <guild>.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Role Name');

role.setPosition(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I tried this but it's still giving me an error. It's the same error I get when using the position parameter in GuildManager.create(). So I guess the roleCreate approach doesn't work either. If you're wondering how I use GuildManager.create(), I've asked a question about it a couple of days ago. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201709/it-works-but-still-getting-this-error-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-discord

Comment: It is impossible because a bot can't set a role's position higher than itself.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I want the admin role to be present after the bot. So that's... position 2? And then the muted role will be 3, etc. But that doesn't seem to work and gives the error. If I higher the number it just messes up the order. I have no clue what to do anymore. :(